# Filter item in dictionary inside a list

Tags: python

I searched for this issue and found many similar questions, but.. none that I could either understood the answer or could transform to my use case.

I know how to filter a response like this `{"type":"hello"}`,
`response['type']` 
`>>> hello` 
But when I got this `[{"mail_address":"hello@mail.com"}]` I was a bit lost..
I've tried a couple of ways, and the last solution I settled on was a bit ugly...

```
res= [{"mail_address":"hello@mail.com"}]  <-- using request method>
body = (res.text)
a = body[18:100]    <--- 100, because I don't really know the length of the mail>
b = ''.join(a.split())
foo = b[:-3]
print(foo)
>>> hello@mail.com
```

I wonder , There must be a better \ cleaner way ?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to achieve ? Is it to extract the email address ? In that case I would suggest doing `print(res[0]['mail_address'])`

Comment: I get this error when trying: TypeError: 'Response' object does not support indexing.   tried res.content, res.text, res.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you indeed are getting what looks to be a JSON string as a response from some web call then perhaps the following can help.

```
import json

s = '[{"mail_address":"hello@mail.com"}]'  # from resp.text

o = json.loads(s)

print(o[0]['mail_address'])
```